# Spring security jdbc config to auth user with multiple roles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, spring-annotations

I am currently working on a java based invoice app.
What I need is , to auth a user with multiple Roles, e.g  Peter should have role ROLE_SETTING,ROLE_REPORT,ROLE_QUOTE,  while Anne only has one role ROLE_SETTING etc...

Here is my spring-security-config.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">  

 <http auto-config="true">  
  <access-denied-handler error-page="/403page" />  
  <intercept-url pattern="/makebill*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_MAKEBILL" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/report*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_REPORT" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/stock*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_STOCK" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/customer*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_CUSTOMER" />
  <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/setting*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SETTING" />   -->
  <intercept-url pattern="/mainmenu*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_MAKEBILL,ROLE_SETTING,ROLE_CUSTOMER,ROLE_REPORT,ROLE_STOCK" />  
  <form-login 
    login-page='/login' username-parameter="username"  
   password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/mainmenu"  
   authentication-failure-url="/login?authfailed" />  
  <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />  
 </http>  

 <authentication-manager> 
     <authentication-provider>  
        <jdbc-user-service 
            data-source-ref="dataSource"  
            users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from person where username=?"  
            authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from person, role where username =?  " />  
     </authentication-provider> 
 </authentication-manager> 


</beans:beans>
```

the authentication-manager currently working fine with just one role, what i mean is...when the sql query `authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from person, role where username =?  "`  runs, if the returned value is just one role, e.g `ROLE_REPORT`,  the application works fine,  but if have a record in db like,  `ROLE_REPORT,ROLE_SETTING,ROLE_CUSTOMER`   , when the query retrieves this value, the application will return me 404 error, it seems I won't be able to grant a user with multiple roles.

Can anyone please point me out what I have done wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: There are few places that you need to fix. First, authorities-by-username-query is not right. I think you're new to SQL query. You're fetching 2 tables without joining them with any key. Please take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455139/users-by-username-query-returns-no-results. This may not fix all of your problem. Let me know if you have another different issue.

Comment: You may find this tutorial helpful: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/

Comment: mkyong's tut is for granting one role for one user, what i need is multiple role for a single user...

Comment: I'm afraid there is no one or two-line fix. You may have to have your own UserDetails and set authorities so that your user will have multiple roles. I found myself this tutorial site helpful. It's a bit different than the way you're doing because you seem not to use JPA or hibernate. http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself,  implemented my own UserDetails, here are the code

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  User buildUserFromUserEntity(Person person) {

    String username = person.getUsername();
    String password = person.getPassword();
    boolean enabled = true;

    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
    String[] authStrings = person.getRole().split(",");
    for(String authString : authStrings) {
        System.out.println("all auth roles: " + authString);
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authString));
    }


    User user = new User(username, password, enabled,
      true, true, true, authorities);

    return user;
  }
}






@Service("userDetailsService") 
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired private PersonService personService;
  @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
      throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

    UserDetails userDetails = null;
    Person person = null;

    List<Person> listPeople = personService.listPeople();
    for (Person p: listPeople) {
        if (p.getUsername().equals(username)) {
            person = p;
        }
    }

    if (person == null)
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");

    return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
  }
}
```

and here is the spring-security-config.xml

```
<http auto-config="true">  
  <access-denied-handler error-page="/403page" />  
  <intercept-url pattern="/makebill*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_MAKEBILL" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/report*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_REPORT" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/stock*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_STOCK" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/customer*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_CUSTOMER" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/setting*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SETTING" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/mainmenu*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_MAKEBILL,ROLE_SETTING,ROLE_CUSTOMER,ROLE_REPORT,ROLE_STOCK" />  
  <form-login 
    login-page='/login' username-parameter="username"  
   password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/mainmenu"  
   authentication-failure-url="/login?authfailed" />  
  <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />  
 </http>  


 <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
 class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
  <beans:property name="providers">
    <beans:list>
      <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">

  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I am now able to assign multiple roles to a single user perfectly.
Thanks for reading :)